# Test Bot Framework v4 started on WSL using Bot Framework Emulator started on Windows

Tags: botframework, wsl-2

I have Bot Framework Emulator v4 started on Windows, and I tried to run sample bots using C#, Typescript or Java. I all cases, bot started on WSL is not reachable for the emulator, when the same bot, started on Windows (the same machine where is the emualtor) is connected immediately with the emulator. Question - how to setup windows / wsl / emulator to run and develop bot based on Bot Framework V4 on WSL? Just to mention: my WSL hosts perfectlyhttp applications, so there is not a connection problem between windows <-> WSL

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ngrok to create a tunnel and connect emulator (or another channel, such as Azure) to a bot running within WSL. See [debugging a channel with Ngrok](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-debug-channel-ngrok?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) for more information.